# How to fix "Failed to scroll to visible" errors after invalid hit points computed during UI tests in Xcode 14.1+?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

Our Xcode UI tests were working fine locally and on our CI but suddenly a few spots started failing when we upgraded to Xcode 14.1 (issue is also present on Xcode 14.2).

The affected areas involve scroll views and tapping a button (no `UITableView` here). These failures occur much of the time, but not always.

When a test fails in these spots the logs show that the computed hit point for the button is `{-1, -1}` which is invalid because it's off screen (the button is clearly not on screen and if you print out its frame in the console it has valid coordinates). When it doesn't fail the computed hit point is a valid point and it is able to tap the button without issue. In all cases the test is able to find the button and `exists` is `true`.

The button isn't even always scrolled out of sight. But even if the test needs to scroll to get the button, `tap` will always successfully scroll to the button, it just can't tap it if it computes an invalid hit point.

e.g.

> t =  2369.32s         Check for interrupting elements affecting "Close" Button
> t =  2369.38s         Synthesize event
> t =  2369.40s             Scroll element to visible
> t =  2369.40s             Find the "Close" Button
> t =  2369.43s             Computed hit point {-1, -1} after scrolling to visible
> t =  2369.43s             Failed: Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) Button, {{338.0, 51.0}, {36.0, 36.0}}, label: 'Close', error: Error kAXErrorCannotComplete performing AXAction kAXScrollToVisibleAction on element AX element pid: 28238, elementOrHash.elementID: 4624960864.301

I have tried many different things including adding a `swipeUp` or `swipeDown` before the tap, adding a `waitForExistence` before the `tap` and a couple other ideas, but nothing has worked consistently.

Is this just an obscure bug in Xcode 14.1+ or is there a fix for this I haven't considered? Never had anything quite like this in Xcode 14 and earlier. But haven't seen any recent complaints around this, and this does seem like a fairly common setup to have in a UI test.

There are a couple pretty old questions complaining of similar-sounding issues but they aren't quite the same and don't have relevant solutions.

Comment: I've seen this happen when an element is barely on screen. I think there is a bug in XCUITest when it comes to scrolling to visible. Can you verify for hittable prior to tapping and scroll up or down if it isn't? Or manually scroll, but slowly (less than a "screen" at a time)? Or catch the error, swipe a tiny bit, and try again?

Comment: Prior to tapping the button may not necessarily be hittable, because it's off screen, but `tap` can scroll to it automatically. How would you catch the error? `tap` doesn't throw.

Comment: Write a manual swipeUntilHittable function?

Comment: Yea, have tried that here, unfortunately still fails sometimes. Seems the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: You have e-mail :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I found your website and sent you an email. Didn't want to post as an answer as I don't think it'll help.

Comment: oh. Interesting snippet, will give it some thought thanks. fyi tools like [gist](https://gist.github.com/) are a bit easier for such things in case you weren't already aware of it.